# Prometheus doesn't have metrics from taskmanager if flink job started

Tags: apache-flink

I operate flink 1.15.2 on Kubernetes and set metric configuration for Flink Cluster as below

```
# metrics
metrics.reporters: prom
metrics.reporter.prom.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporter
```

The problem is that prometheus doesn't get metrics from taskmanager if the flink job has started.
If I stopped the job, then I could see the metrics however some metrics are empty.

1. I tried to reduce CPU usage but still no metric from taskmanager
2. I tried to  increase task slot, still no metric
3. It happens to both Intel and ARM node
4. I tried to change flink config as below, metircs were collocted for a moment(several seconds) and disappeared again

```
# metrics
metrics.reporters: prom
metrics.reporter.prom.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporterFactory
```

5. I tried to change flink config as below, but still no metric

```
kafkaSourceBuilder.setProperty("register.consumer.metrics", "false");
var producerProperties = new Properties();
producerProperties.setProperty("register.producer.metrics", "false");
producerSinkBuilder.setKafkaProducerConfig(producerProperties);
```

6. If I try to start job on flink 1.15.3, metircs were collocted
7. If I try to start job on flink 1.16.0,  Prometheus doesn't have any metric from flink at all

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the release notes of Flink 1.16, configuring reporters by their class has been deprecated. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/release-notes/flink-1.16/#flink-27206httpsissuesapacheorgjirabrowseflink-27206 for details.

There are also some known issues with metrics reporting in 1.16.0; please upgrade to Flink 1.16.1.